# Save PowerPoints as ppsx with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerpoint, slideshow

I'm pretty new to using PowerShell and would like some guidens in how to achieve the following.

I have a .pptx-file in one folder and I would like to save this as a ppsx (SlideShow) in an other folder.

I've been searching around the internet and haven't found any good code examples of how to do this.

I'm thinking I somehow need to specify where to find the .pptx-file, then use a function such as presentaion.SaveCopyAs("file name", SaveAsShow), and then specify where to save it? Or at least move the copied file to intended destination.

I have the intention of running this PowerShell script with PowerAutomate so I can automatically update the slideshow and share it with other people in the organisasation.

Thank you to anyone who have any help.

Comment: If you found a solution: _please post a real answer below_, not in the question itself - this will also allow you to accept your own answer and get some reputation points :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Two points: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Two: [ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/5211833), i.e. posting an answer generated by it may lead to sanctions against your account

Comment: Thank you for your contributions, i'll take both to heart and remember them going forward on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that can save the powerpoint in the intended way.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

# Create a PowerPoint application object
$powerpoint = New-Object -ComObject PowerPoint.Application

# Open the PowerPoint presentation
$presentation = $powerpoint.Presentations.Open("C:\filepath\document.pptx")

# Save the presentation as a PowerPoint Show
$presentation.SaveAs("C:filepath\Name", [Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType]::ppSaveAsOpenXMLShow)

# Close the presentation and quit PowerPoint
$presentation.Close() 
Stop-Process -name POWERPNT -Force
```

Now instead of using `PowerAutomate` to run this script, I will try to use Task Scheduler to run the script at a specific time. It can be a problem since I might not have the administrative rigths, since I need "Log on as batch job rights", which I dont have ATM.